# MS Access enter parameter value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form and in the form is a sub form that displays rows from a query. One of the columns in the subform is the DNANumber. The report works 100%. Problem is, when I call the report using the following code,

```
strWhereClause = "[DNANumber]=" & strText
DoCmd.OpenReport "Certificate", acViewPreview, , strWhereClause, , acHidden
```

I get a popup message asking for the parameter value, also displaying that exact value it is looking for above the textfield. I have checked all the spelling in the queries, forms , subforms and tables and controlls. Everything is fine. Why do I get this popup message. Further, If I type in the value, it displays the report without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If `[DNANumber]` is text data type, add quotes around the value of `strText` when you build `strWhereClause`.

```vb
strWhereClause = "[DNANumber]='" & strText & "'"
```